# When are elements of a (perfect) semidirect product simple commutators?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semidirect-product

I have a semidirect product and I have shown that it is perfect. However, I would like to know whether every element is a simple commutator (rather than a product of commutators). I am not aware of any general results in this direction, so if someone could provide one, I would be grateful.

In any event, I will describe the specific setup I have below, and if someone would like to offer specific insights, I would, likewise, be appreciative.

Start with any finite field $\mathbb{F}$. Let $m\geq 1$ be an integer and consider $Sp_{2m}(\mathbb{F})$, the group of symplectic matrices (over $\mathbb{F}$) with the natural (right) action on the vector space $\mathbb{F}^{2m}$.

Every element $v\in \mathbb{F}^{2m}$ can be realized as $v=w^{A}-w$ for an appropriate choice of $A\in Sp_{2m}(\mathbb{F})$ and $w\in \mathbb{F}^{2m}$. The element $w^A-w$ is a commutator in the semidirect product. Moreover, if $|\mathbb{F}|\geq 3$ and $m\geq 2$, then every element of $Sp_{2m}(\mathbb{F})$ is a commutator (in the symplectic group).

Is this enough to show that elements of the semidirect product are commutators? If not, what would be a sufficient condition?